# Matching routes in config/routes.rb to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, routes

So I'm trying to post to a 'toggle_live' action in my PollsController but am getting a 'No routes matching" error.  Advice here would be really awesome!  Thanks!

**It's configured in routes like so:**

```
post "polls/toggle_live"
```

**Here's the action in the PollsController:**

```
  def toggle_live
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {@poll.toggle_live}
    end

  end
```

**Here's the form that initiates the request:**

```
= link_to "Start",:method => :post, :action => :toggle_live, :remote=>true, :class=> 'btn btn-success btn-small start-poll'
```

Comment: could you add the output of rake routes?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes), it would be easier:

routes.rb:

```
post 'polls/toggle_live' => 'polls#toggle_live', :as => 'toggle_live'
```

In the view:

```
= link_to "Start", toggle_live_path, {:method => :post, :remote=>true}, {:class=> 'btn btn-success btn-small start-poll'}
```